# Hot code deploy issue in vscode with spring controller

Tags: java, tomcat, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I've Spring web MVC project with java configuration. I'm facing a strange issue in Vscode IDE that I can see hot code deploy with services and doa's but can't in the controllers. Why is that? Are there any limitations?

I'm seeing this error when made changes in @Controller
[image]

And this error stack trace on debug console-
[image]

Comment: Avdhesh, I am facing the same issue but it's working on other layers like service and dao.